# How to use JavaScript to flush the memory of the browser to hide it from memory reading tools esp WinHex?

Tags: javascript, memory, browser-cache

The POST request on the Login page containing the username and password of the user is stored in the browser memory. The browser's memory can be read using memory-reading tools like WinHex. An adversary with access to the user's open browser, after logout, can thus steal the password from the memory.
How can I use JavaScript to flush the memory of the browser or browser-cache?

One option I have is to encrypt passwords, but that is a lengthy process. Can't JavaScript do the job?

Comment: sounds interesting, can you reveal some more details on the real goals ?

Comment: Thanks. Well the real goal is to prevent any unauthorized access to application's database via browser's memory. There are tools like WinHex which can read variables saved in a browser's memory. I hope I am clear.

Comment: The standard approach is to, upon logout, give the user a message that they have logged out and should close the browser for security purposes. My bank does it, as do government websites here in Aus. Is this unsuitable?

Comment: Yes, it is. Even we provide our user with this warning. But I can't rely on my user's behavior for security of my application. I am trying to find ways to rub the passwords off the browser's memory via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to use salted hashing technique.

This technique ensures that even if someone reads the memory the password is not visible in clear text. Also, it is impossible to retrieve the password as the attacker would require the salt that was used to hash the password before transmission.

http://palisade.plynt.com/issues/2004Aug/passwords-in-memory/

http://plynt.com/blog/2006/06/sending-salted-hashes-just-got/

Comment: thanks, but as I mentioned, I wanted to avoid encrypting via any means.

Comment: Two things - the hash is now the password, so there is no additional protection to the user using this kind of method except that their original password is not exposed. Also any encryption/salting done client-side (i.e. in the browser) inherently exposes both the encryption method and the salt, which makes it pretty simple to reverse engineer it and look for ways to find the original password. Depending on the password strength, it may not be feasible, but simple passwords could be retrieved fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. JavaScript provides no manual memory management features or ability to force clear the user's cache.

Comment: yeah, agreed. Is there a way to assign the variables with some other value or some similar way to prevent password being clearly visible in browser memory?

Comment: Well, you were right. Tried a lot of ways, but passwords were very well visible with hacking tools.